# Reading lines until empty string, then multiplying them

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I have a little question here about the Haskell IO. I have been programming in haskell for some time now, but for the love of me I can't seem to wrap my head around I/O.

The assignment is simple - read integers from the standard input and multiply them. Here's what I've got so far:

```
mulnum n = do a <- getLine
           if a == "" then n else mulnum (n * (read a :: Int))

mulInput :: IO ()
mulInput = print (mulnum 1)
```

The error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b' with actual type `Int'
Relevant bindings include
  n :: IO b (bound at dayx.hs:8:8)
  mulnum :: IO b -> IO b (bound at dayx.hs:8:1)
In the second argument of `(*)', namely `(read a :: Int)'
In the first argument of `mulnum', namely `(n * (read a :: Int))'
In the expression: mulnum (n * (read a :: Int))
```

I have a strong suspicion that I'm looking at it from the wrong perspective, so if anyone could at least point me in the right direction, I'd be extremely happy.

Thanks and have a nice day!

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot for the help! This is what it looks like now:

```
mulnum :: Int -> IO Int
mulnum n = do a <- getLine
              let a1 = (read a :: Int) in if a == "" then return n else mulnum (n * a1)

mulInput :: IO ()
mulInput = mulnum 1 >>= print
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you just need to say `... then return n else ...`

Your second problem is here:

```
print (mulnum 1)
```

which should be:

```
do n <- mulnum 1
   print n
```

or:

```
mulnum 1 >>= print
```

Explanation:

Since you are in the IO monad, both clauses of the if-then-else must be IO computations. The else part is since it is a recursive call to `mulnum`, but `n` by itself is a pure value. By writing `return n` you make it monadic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've included the final code in the original post :)

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, you generally want to exploit laziness and separate the impure (I/O) and pure (computation) parts.

Reading in all lines until you hit an empty one is I/O. Everything else is computation.

So you want a function that gives you lines of input until you reach an empty one. You probably want to return the result as a list of strings; that's already lazy.

One way to do this is this:

```
getLines :: IO [String]
getLines = lines <$> getContents
```

Which roughly means "call `getContents` and then apply `lines` to the result". `getContents` reads the entire standard input, but it does so lazily. `lines` splits a string into lines; again, lazily.

(Note: Lazy I/O has its share of problems, which lead to the development of pipeline libraries like pipes and conduit, but for this simple example, the problems don't matter.)

Now, you just have to cut that at the first empty line:

```
main = do
  lines <- getLines
  let leadingLines = takeWhile (not . null) lines
```

Now that you have the leading lines, all that remains is to parse each line (which is a `map`) and multiply them (which is a `fold`, but there's the specialized `product` which does exactly that).

Here we omit checking that the numbers parse correctly.

```
  let p = (product $ map read leadingLines) :: Int
```

I've added an explicit type annotation, because otherwise Haskell can't decide what numeric type you want.

Finally, you can print out the result.

```
  print p
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! This seems like a different approach to these things, I'll keep all of this in mind